# XPages dynamicContent control: an eventHandler is incorrectly triggered

Tags: javascript, dom-events, xpages

Using a DynamicContent control seems to be too difficult for me. Below a simple example that *appears* to work: I click a city, page2 is displayed, I click BACK and page1 is shown again. So far so good.

Now, I reload the page (F5), I click a city and then I click somewhere on the page... strangely, the BACK action is executed. I click again somewhere (sometimes a third click is required), and then an error 500 shows up: "javax.faces.FacesException: CLFAD0380E: No component found with ID $$xspsubmitid=view:_id1:_id2:dynamicContent1:_id14 to handle the submit event.".

What I *assume* is that the eventListener on the BACK-action should have been removed but still exists.

For the rest, it's baffling to me. If someone could be so kind as to shed some light on this? Thanks!!

Other info: Domino V11.0, Domino Designer V11.0.1, it happens both in Firefox and Chromium (latest), all systems running Linux (except for the Designer).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:panel id="thisPanel" styleClass="thisPanel">
        <xe:dynamicContent id="dynamicContent1" defaultFacet="page1">
            <xp:this.facets>
                <xp:div xp:key="page1">
                    <xp:label value="Welcome!" id="label8" styleClass="header"></xp:label>
                    <xp:div id="eventList" styleClass="eventList">
                        <xp:repeat var="city" value="#{javascript:['Paris','London']}">
                            <xp:div styleClass="category clickable">
                                <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField1" value="#{city}">
                                    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="thisPanel" disableValidators="true">
                                        <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dynamicContent1").show("page2");
    }]]></xp:this.action>
                                    </xp:eventHandler>
                                </xp:text>
                            </xp:div>
                        </xp:repeat>
                    </xp:div>
                </xp:div>
                <xp:div xp:key="page2">
                    <xp:div styleClass="back clickable">
                        BACK
                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="partial" refreshId="thisPanel" disableValidators="true">
                            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dynamicContent1").show("page1");}]]></xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>  
                    </xp:div>
                </xp:div>
            </xp:this.facets>
        </xe:dynamicContent>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:view>
```

---

**UPDATE**

A "fix" seems to be to set

```
xsp.error.disable.0380=true
```

The error is no longer there, but what exactly happens internally I don't know.

Comment: I managed to make it work using client-side calls, I now use XSP.showContent in both event handlers.

Comment: The error also happens elsewhere, using client-side JS.